# Can't mount shared folder in Ubuntu 12.10 Server Guest Virtual Box

Tags: 12.10, mount, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have filled out the shared folder options in Settings -> Shared Folders of a shared folder with a name of 'share'. It is set to automount but when I start up the guest OS, nothing is showing up in the `/media` folder.

I run the following command

`sudo mount -t vboxsf share /home/mo/local/`

it gives me the error

`/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mount failed with the error: No such device`

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to do with not having the correct linux headers installed and therefore having a bad install of the Guest Additions.

in console:

```
uname -r
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-<uname -r>
```

then I reinstalled the guest additions from ISO provided from Oracle, not the guest additions from the default repository.

Was able to mount after this